# How to know how how many capacitors to use for voltage smoothing?

Tags: capacitor, decoupling-capacitor, esp32

I am working on a PCB that uses the ESP32-S2. In its design guidelines Expressif gives this image:

[image]

> Pin1, pin3, pin4, pin20, pin51, and pin54 are the analog power supply
> pins, working at 2.8 V ~ 3.6 V. It should be noted that the sudden
> increase in current draw, when ESP32-S2 is in transmission mode, may
> cause a power rail collapse. Therefore, it is highly recommended to
> add another 10 µF capacitor to the power trace, which can work in
> conjunction with the 0.1 µF capacitor. In addition, a CLC filter
> circuit needs to be added near the power pins (pin3 and pin4) so as to
> suppress high-frequency harmonics. The inductor’s rated current is
> preferably 500 mA or above. Refer to Figure 3 and place the
> appropriate decoupling capacitor near each analog power pin.

If I am powering up the ESP through a voltage regulator, why is this needed? Also, how can I tell what capacitor to use where it says TBD?

Comment: Sometimes the sudden increase in current draw is so huge that the voltage regulator doesn't have "time" for convert the extra current in order to keep the output line with the nominal voltage. The capacitor will sustain the voltage to power the microcontroller in those critical micro-seconds that the regulator needs to keep up to the increase.

Comment: Your pcb layout has a big part to play in the operation of this circuit as does the specific choice of components. TBD means you need to factor in your choice of component and layout to determine what value to use. Eg C11, L2 and C12 form a matching network for the antenna. If you don't know the requirements of the antenna, then you can't solve the values. You'll probably need expensive test equipment to validate your choice. You're better off using a module where all the evil has been taken care of and tested to comply with various standards.

Answer (score 2):

The 2nH is just the PCB copper trace of about 3mm. (est. 0.6 nH/mm for typical power tracks. (+/-50% depending on l/w ratio)

The caps go at the common input as your voltage source.  The 2nH is your trace inductance that can compute using the free Sierra PCB design .exe tools.  I estimate that allows you place the TBD chip cap about 3mm away from the source caps. So the IC needs to be place right near the source.

The CLC filter has an RC load from all the CMOS switches.

You need to model every part in a filter and be able to estimate the dynamic RC values of the chip. This only comes from experience. The supply has an RLC impedance, the wires and traces have a RLC impedance and so do all capacitors. Even the chip has an RC impedance depending on how many gates switch synchronously their 25 to 50 ohm load with a Coss of each driver.

I could model this with some effort , but I suggest you have no reason to deviate from the design layouts given.. Use low ESR caps and the distance of 3 mm is significant, which can produce 1 to 20 MHz resonance depending on all the assumptions of the above.  Q will increase with L and tack lengths between caps. Use metal film 0.1 uF is good but keeping traces as close to the supply edge is critical with these nanosecond risetime signals.

Here is a quick and dirty guestimate of using low ESR caps and injecting a sweep thru the chip's RC equivalent looking at the suppression of noise on Vdd with the supply source on the left.

R is the parallel equivalent value of the RdsOn and Coss during a transition at Vdd/2 which assuming you can estimate the chips used inside.  I can't but others might have IC design wisdom for this chip.

Keep your trace stripline impedances low and very short and that is how they designed their layout.
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

The actual circuit model will have a dozen more RLC values to be more accurate but L is dominant with the big C and ESR ratios determine the plateau attenuation.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BhIEN.jpg